# When should I use <tag>content</tag> tag style, when <tag attrs> and when <tag attrs />?

Tags: html, html5

I'm using HTML5.

I just a bit confused that some people said "html validator does not like `<tag attrs />` tags style". It is obvious that if I need to place some content between opening and closing tag I should use `<tag>`content`</tag>` tag style. But if not, which one is right?

```
<tag attrs />
<tag attrs>
```

For example: what is the correct use of `<br />` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/syntax.html#void-elements) (like `br`) MUST NOT have an [end tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/syntax.html#end-tags) nor content, so they are *empty* (sometimes also called *self-closing*).
- [Foreign elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/syntax.html#foreign-elements) (like `svg`) MAY be self-closing.
- No other elements may be self-closing.

(Note that you can [omit the end/start tags of some elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/syntax.html#optional-tags), but that doesn’t make them self-closing, i.e., they can still have content.)

Now, when you have a void element (resp. a self-closing foreign element), does its start tag end with `>` or `/>`? The [HTML5 spec says about start tags in step 6](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag):

> Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single "/" (U+002F) character. This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it marks the start tag as self-closing.

So for void elements, it’s up to you. You can use `<br>` or `<br />`, they are  equivalent.

(For foreign elements, you should add the slash if you need to mark it as self-closing; this probably depends on their specification resp. your use case.)

In XHTML5 or [(X)HTML5 polyglot documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-polyglot/#empty-elements), you MUST add the `/` for void elements.

Answer (score 2):

`tag`, `attrs` and `rel` are not valid in HTML5. For adding data to elements you should now [use data-](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/). In terms of correct usage [**br**](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/WD/wds2p3.html) you can use `<br>` without the [***ending slash***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br) as generally you do not need to use `<img src="" alt==" />` `<br />` etc in HTML5. I recommend you hop over to [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) as the answers on that site are pretty solid and will answer all these type of questions. Furthermore for coding related questions please use [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).